# What is the closest equivalent of "Python interpreter" for C#?

Tags: .net, ide

Here is what I mean:

Python interpreter is a great tool for checking something quickly and then throwing it away.

For instance, I wish to examine how `NameValueCollection` behaves in .Net (since the new MSDN help sucks so much).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.get.aspx

I tried using http://www.linqpad.net/ but it barks at using statements.

I am looking for something like that - a tiny IDE which has powerful code completion, where I can try things quickly. VS2008 is too bulky for that.

So, any recommendations? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the closest one is the [Mono C# interactive shell](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

Comment: Hm ... would that mess with the existing .Net installation? Also, there is some difference between Mono libs and .Net libs. I surely hope to understand more about .Net peculiarities and not Mono peculiarities. Great fin anyway!